# Is it ok not to place headers on pages?

Tags: consistency, header, sidebar

Do I need a header on the top of every page I have or is a prominent indication of category in the sidebar enough? I keep jumping back and forth and cannot come up with a permanent solution. It also affects a few later parts of the project - due to consistency, so I am a bit struggling, because on some pages it seems ok and on some something seems missing.

I'd like to leave them out, but is it ok for sure not to give the user the indication on the top of the page, just in the sidebar?

This site right here does it - when you go to the user's page (yours or someone else's) there are tabs on the top, but the main content is below, with the name and the rest of the info. And I think it's easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users **will** need context for the information you are presenting - If you can provide sufficient context using the indicator in the side bar then you may not need anything else.

Unfortunately, the only way to be certain is to test this with your target users. Try testing different groups of users with both variations to see which is more effective.